# How to terminate a process using multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

When I click the `srch` button `srch_kwrds1` is executed and I expected that when I click the `stp` button the function `srch_kwrds1` would be terminated and the output to the console would be 0 but the output is 0 followed by 1 meaning `srch_kwrds1` was not really terminated. How can I terminate `srch_kwrds1`?

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Div
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import curdoc
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


class Callbacks:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0

    def srch_kwrds1(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        layout.children[2] = Div(text='done!') 
        print(self.i + 1)

    def srch_kwrds(self):
        layout.children.insert(2, srch_txt)
        self.p = Process(target=self.srch_kwrds1) 
        self.p.start()
        
    def stp_srch(self):
        self.p.terminate()
        srch_txt.text = 'stopped'
        print(self.i)


cb = Callbacks()

srch = Button(label='search')
srch.on_click(cb.srch_kwrds)

stp = Button(label='stop')
stp.on_click(cb.stp_srch)

srch_txt = Div(text='searching')

layout = column(srch, stp)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

When I just press the `strt` button the layout is not updated to show "done!". How can I update the layout?

I have asked this question in the [Bokeh Discourse](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/interrupting-a-slow-callback-from-another-callback/6422/5) but I didn't get an answer there because the question is more of a multiprocessing question than a Bokeh question and I did not think it would be appropriate to pursue further over there.

Comment: What is your goal with using a Process in srch_kwrds? What effect would you like to achieve?

Comment: I would like to be able to terminate the ```srch_kwrds1``` when I click the ```stp``` button.

Comment: Yes, I understand you want it to terminate. But why do you start it at all?

Comment: @xxa They have an empty placeholder  (`time.sleep(5)`) for now. I assume later they'll make it conduct a search.

Comment: I am not familiar with this graphics library, but are you sure you can just modify layout.children directly like that, with inserts and assignments, instead of calling some other method to add and change GUI elements? Even if you can, there's a high possibility of a race condition because you're not using mutexes or anything like that to make sure the processes don't interfere with each other.

Comment: Also, friendly suggestion: you'd be better off if you didn't omit vowels all the time in your method names. It can make them much more unreadable and cumbersome if you have to keep parsing the names and looking them up than if you just kept a couple more characters.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Fine, search is long running, but a Process is a heavyweight component, and interaction with it is not straightforward. A Thread might be a good solution if a Process is not mandatory.

Comment: @xxa Yes, that's what I agree with in my answer below.

Comment: @xxa, yes, a long running search is conducted by calling a function from another script and that function calls many other functions while chunking the data and performing the search using multiple processes. Once the search is completed a series of filter and aggregation functions from ```Callbacks``` are called by ```srch_kwrds1```. I agree that threads may be more appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: @Anonymous1847, thanks for the suggestion about not omitting vowels, I'll keep that in mind from here onwards. I am sure that ```layout.children``` can be modified in the manner used in the code in the question but it is not updating while using the Process because there is no communication between the processes as mentioned in the Bokeh Discourse discussion about this question (link in question).

Answer (score 0):

The multiprocessing module in Python does not share memory by default. Your GUI is running in your original process; the new process cannot access it directly. I would suggest using threading instead or setting up `SharedMemory` objects to pass data back and forth between the processes.

Multithreading will allow you to do other things in the meantime while your search is being conducted, but won't let you fully utilize multiple CPU cores. It also will allow memory to be shared between threads, given that you use proper measures, e.g. mutexes (look on Python docs for the class `Lock`), to ensure no two threads are accessing the same memory at the same time in a conflicting way. Depending on your application this may be OK. If you want true concurrency with multiple CPU cores doing different things at the same time, you can use multiprocessing, but again you'll need to explicitly set up memory sharing. I would recommend against sharing GUI data, as that can often be very interlinked and process-dependent. Since you're doing a search, you should find it easier to share strings and simpler data like that, which then the main process can read and display on the GUI.

As an example using threading and a tkinter GUI:

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread, Lock

thread = None
stop = None
search_result_label = None
label_lock = Lock()

def do_search():
    global stop
    global search_result_label
    global label_lock
    s = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        for j in range(10000):
            s += i * j
            if stop:
                return
    with label_lock:
        search_result_label["text"] = "Search result: {}".format(s)

def start_search():
    global thread
    global stop
    thread = Thread(target = do_search)
    stop = False
    thread.start()

def stop_search():
    global stop
    global search_result_label
    global label_lock
    stop = True
    with label_lock:
        search_result_label["text"] = "Search stopped"

root = Tk()
div = Frame(root)
div.grid()

search_button = Button(div, text = "Search")
search_button["command"] = start_search
search_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

stop_button = Button(div, text = "Stop")
stop_button["command"] = stop_search
stop_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

search_result_label = Label(div, text = "Empty results")
search_result_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Of course, you probably won't just be adding a hundred million numbers in order in your search function, but most computation-intensive functions have a loop of some sort, and you can check if stop has been set each time through that loop. Unfortunately stopping threads is not as simple as just calling some method terminate() (although in many cases you wouldn't want to anyway, as it could cause memory leakage and other problems). Notice how I used a lock around accesses to the label, since it can be accessed by multiple threads.

Comment: Can you please modify the code in the question to use a thread instead of a process? I acknowledge that you are not familiar with Bokeh and I don't expect you to test the answer before posting it. I'm happy to try your answer and comment here if it doesn't work.

Comment: @PSK Sure, give me a moment.

Comment: Thanks but setting a variable that I need to check is what I was trying to avoid because that wouldn't be an instant stop and even then I would have to check for the variable in multiple places. I also suspected that threads cannot be stopped using a terminate() kind of function and that's why I used a process instead even though it is heavyweight. I understand that what I'm doing is not the best practice and that the real problem may be bad design of the code. But, how do I make the ```Process``` ```self.p``` terminate when I click the ```stp``` button and update the layout?

Comment: @PSK Technically there is another way to stop the thread, by raising an exception within it, but it's lower level and a little finicky as there's no support for it in the threading module itself. First you `import ctypes`, then when you want to stop the thread you write `ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(th._thread_id, ctypes.py_object(SystemExit))`, where `th` is the thread. Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Source is https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/ , btw.